# absolute positioning of img in popup

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I'm having a lot of issues positioning an image (arrow) within a pop-up window. Using positioning relative to the box, I can't move the img to exactly the right place.

So I tried absolute or, rather, placing a div within a div (excerpt shown.)

```
<div style="position:relative;top:0px;bottom:500px;left:100px">
<img src="my_image.png" style="position:absolute" height="50" width="100" alt="Arrow pointing to the top right corner of the page" />
</div>
```

However, now that it's not relative to the rest of the box, it doesn't really move - just expands the pop-up.

Is there anyway to do what I want? Am I on the right track?

Cheers!

Edit: This arrow is supposed to point to the header (pop up says "In the header..."); I don't particularly like this set up but can't think of anything else. If you've got a better idea please post :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have a combination like this:

- Your parent element (the container div, i.e. the popup) needs to have position:relative or absolute
- Your child (the arrow) needts to have: position:absolute,top:123px,left:245px (top and left indicate its position relative to the containing element).

The width and the height of the img are useless, unless you are reducing or expanding the IMG, which you should not do: drop them. I do not understand whether the div in your code is just a wrapper to the arrow, or is the popup container. In the first case you could just drop it, and set display:block to the img element.

Comment: hi Palantir - thanks for the reply. It is a wrapper to the arrow, but why drop it? Especially when you said I need to include position:absolute... in the child div

Answer (score 0):

You'd be beter making it a background image of the div.

```
<div style="background-image: url('my_image.png'); background-position:top right; background-repeat:no-repeat;">

</div>
```

Comment: Create a JS Fiddle and Ill help if i can. That was kinda pseudo code and may not be 100% accurate

Comment: sure, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kJYug/ (I've never created a Fiddle before, so I apologize that it doesn't look so great)